# Using Susy with Compass - what files should be installed?

Tags: symfony, compass-sass, sass, susy-compass

I'm trying to use Susy as the grid element in a project

http://susy.oddbird.net/

FYI I'm also using the following libraries

- Compass
- Assetic
- Symfony (2.x)
- Ubuntu (10.4)

When I try to import susy in my sass file

```
@import "compass/reset"
@import "compass/css3"
@import "susy" <- This line causes a server internal error (500)
```

I'm sure that this is because compass is unable to locate the susy files to include. Can someone with a successful installation please tell me where these susy files should be located? After installing the compass-susy-plugin using gem installer I can see the following...

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:/$ locate susy
/home/ubuntu/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.11.5/examples/susy
/home/ubuntu/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.11.5/examples/susy/bootstrap.rb
/home/ubuntu/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.11.5/examples/susy/clean.rb
/home/ubuntu/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.11.5/examples/susy/config.rb
/home/ubuntu/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.11.5/examples/susy/src
/home/ubuntu/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.11.5/examples/susy/src/_base.scss
/home/ubuntu/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.11.5/examples/susy/src/_defaults.scss
/home/ubuntu/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.11.5/examples/susy/src/screen.scss
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.11.5/examples/susy
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.11.5/examples/susy/bootstrap.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.11.5/examples/susy/clean.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.11.5/examples/susy/config.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.11.5/examples/susy/src
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.11.5/examples/susy/src/_base.scss
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.11.5/examples/susy/src/_defaults.scss
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.11.5/examples/susy/src/screen.scss
```

It only seems to have saved the susy files into the examples folder - should it also have copied them into the 'frameworks' or **libs** folder (it hasnt)?

Or is the above correct - in which case how do the 'import' decelerations in the compass file relate to (from the files system POV) the sass files themselves?

BTW: Everything is working great except for this one issue.

**P.S**
If someone with a rep of over 1500 want to create two new tags then 'Assetic' and 'Susy' should be attached to this post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the susy gem didn't install properly. I uninstalled/reinstalled and the gem now shows up when I do a `gem list` as `compass-susy-plugin`.

Everything now works - I would add that I also needed to add the line `require 'susy'` to my compass configuration.